# Hacks to share data between 'unrelated' programs running on the same JVM?

Tags: java, web-applications

My scenario is that I've got a 2 web-apps running in a servlet container. Although they are in fact related apps, the servlet container assumes that no 2 web-apps are in fact related.  I'd like these web-apps to **share data in a lightweight way ... by referring to the same object on the heap**.  Obviously, that data will have to be expressed entirely in terms of a class defined by some classloader common to both web-apps, but let's assume that `java.lang.String` or `byte[]` will do the job for me.

The trick is then finding some way that each web-app can gain a reference the object-to-be-shared.

For example, if it were allowed by the security manager, one web-app might do:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
   public Object data;
});
```

and then the other web-app could try to use reflection on System.out to try and get a reference to `data`.

But I'll need something which isn't protected by a security manager.  Obviously, the successful hack will effectively be one of the reasons why non-trusted programs can't share a JVM, and might be closed-off in future.  Of *course* it's not supported, is dumb to rely on, needs to synchronize between threads, etc.

The idea is **not to require the modification of the JVM or servlet-container configuration in any way**, just to deploy two web-apps as normal, and abuse the seams of the java.* class library to do something which the JavaEE vendors are keen that you not do.  :-)

Ideas?

Edit1: emphasised the key goals/constraints
Edit2: qualified my use of 'unrelated'

Comment: Why are the following two alternatives not viable for you? (1) Have the two apps run as modules within one supervisor app. (2) Use external files, pipes or the HTTP protocol iteself to communicate.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to couple allegedly unrelated applications like this. Modern practice is moving the other way, breaking up applications into individual services communicating externally.

Comment: @Giorgio basically because (1) requires me to add a framework 'underneath' the Java Servlet API - either to import one or make one ... less is more - I want to achieve modularity with *just* (or despite) the servlet API;  (2) forces me to marshall/unmarshal ... why take the hit on that overhead if I can find another way?

Comment: @chrylis my app is already individual services, but in the scenario where I deploy them all on 1 JVM, why should I take the 'external' hit unnecessarily?

Comment: I agree it is a bad idea though ... this question is more about *can it be done at all*?  (In the spirit of hacking, yeah?).  *Probably* what I will actually end up doing for my app is to package my 'service' (for service it is) in such a fashion that Tomcat can pop it into the JNDI tree of my UI-web-apps as a 'resource'.  However, that's getting non-portable too, and puts more of a burden on the administrator, and pushes me a little more towards *embedding* a servlet container in my app.  Which are not directions I want to take it *right now*.  If I find a good hack, I might take it for now.